# How can PWM be generated on the Raspberry Pi using wiringPi with C?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gpio, pwm

I'm trying to learn C and want to be able to generate a PWM signal on the GPIO pins of a Raspberry Pi. However, most of the tutorials I've followed have led to nothing working. Heres the code im currently using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <softPwm.h>


#define RED 20
#define GREEN 21

// pwm
int pwmValue = 1023;
int pwmValueInit = 0;

int main (void)
{
 
    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
    return -1;

    if (wiringPiSetupSys() == -1)
        return -1;
    
    pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(RED, LOW); // at start turn off the GPIO
    digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW); // at start turn off the GPIO
    pinMode(RED, PWM_OUTPUT);
    pinMode(GREEN, PWM_OUTPUT);
    
    softPwmCreate(RED, pwmValueInit, pwmValue);
    softPwmCreate(GREEN, pwmValueInit, pwmValue);

    int duty;
    printf("Enter the desired duty cycle:\n");
    scanf("%f", duty);
    
    softPwmWrite(RED, duty);
    softPwmWrite(GREEN, duty);
    
    
}
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is as the program compiles with no errors. However, when I run the program it returns a Segmentation Fault but I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Your compiler should warn you that it expects an address as parameter for `scanf`:  `scanf("%f", duty);` You tell the compiler to take an uninitialized integer, interpret the value as an address and write the result of conversion of your input to that random address. Also you request to convert a floating point value but your variable has type `int`.

Comment: Try to [debug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnC5LrTx470) you program and you'll find what line of code lead to SF. In any case you must have [scanf("%d",duty)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) to read integer (int) value. `"%f"` - mean floating point value, it can be an issue, since incorrect stack memory usage.

Comment: By the way, the practice of creating a [mcve] would have allowed you to find this bug on your own.  One of the first steps to making a program more minimal is removing all user input.  If you remove call to `scanf` and replace it with a hardcoded duty cycle and the program starts working, you would know immediately that the user input code was the problem.  I highly recommend making a [mcve] the next time you have trouble with misbehaving code.  Or just put a bunch of printf commands in your code so you can see where it is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

The segfault probably doesn't have to do with WiringPi. Your `scanf()` call is wrong - you must pass the address of the destination variable, not the variable itself. Also, if you want to use an `int`, use the `%d` format specifier.

`scanf("%d", &duty);`

If you still aren't getting your LED to light, it's worth incrementally verifying that your setup is correct. Can you blink the LED (without PWM)? This would verify that you have the correct pin and wiring.

Comment: Yes ive blinked the leds so i know the i have the correct pins and wiring, i had forgot about the pointers so ill add those in now

Comment: Ive added the pointers and it now dosent give a segmentation fault but im still not getting the leds to light up, ill keep looking for a solution